# Different views for different Devise users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have three Devise models in my application: Users, Publishers, and Content Creators.

Publishers inherit from Content Creators, and Content Creators inherit from Users.

I put a custom index.html.erb file in each of these model's view folders that I want to display instead of the default User index.html.erb file, meaning, that if a publisher logs in, I want them to see the index.hml.erb in views/publishers instead of the one in posts.

I have created separate controllers for Content Creators and Publishers that have an index action.
This is currently my routes file:

```
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :publishers , :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_for :content_creators 
  resources :posts 
  get 'tagged' => 'posts#tagged', :as => 'tagged'
  root "posts#index"
```

How can I configure my routes file to do this?

Comment: you can have one controller and in the action redirect to specific controller according to user type

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is a user, in your view you can check by

```
if current_user.publisher?
  <%= render 'view_for_publisher' %>
elsif current_user.content_creator?
  <%= render 'view_for_content_creator' %>
else
  <%= render 'default_view' %>
end
```

or in the controller, instead of render, you can redirect to another action with your desired view.
I hope it'll help.